# Liferay Asset Publisher cannot open web content

Tags: liferay

I have Asset Publisher portlet on my page.

It displays list of documents, but when I click on "Read more" link, it shows blank page instead content.

URL in browser is getting changed.

Comment: can you please more information like what server logs you are getting ?

Comment: problem is there is no logs from liferay..

Comment: have you made any changes in asset publisher using plugin hook?

Comment: nope, just add assset publisher to my portal, no config changes

Comment: So, we find out that problem is with Jboss Wildfly and URI encoding. but we are lost

Comment: Though I think using js to rewrite urls is a viable option, I would recommend tweaking or find some useful setting to let WildFly use your URIs properly. WildFly is a very smart creature, so I think there's already a discussion on Uri encoding.